# How to access WebService method from URL (target namespace in wsdl)? Call webservice from a MSSQL without CLR

Tags: sql, web-services, wsdl, xml-namespaces

Could you tell me how to access a web service method from a web browser? I need it to call a webservice from a database using only TSQL
I have a simple web service running on my local JBoss server.
I have found an information that a wsdl file is easily accessed by calling an URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/webserviceName?wsdl
```

I would like to invoke a method "simpleMethod". As I learned from reading tutorials I should call:

```
http://localhost:8081/webserviceName/simpleMethod
```

but it simply does not work. I have received an error that the requested resource is not available.

In received wsdl file there is a statement:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="DataServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://services.test.com/">
```

Does it make any difference? Should I use that information to call a Web Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea behind my question was to find a way to call a webservice from a database (and that is why I needed web service URL).

So I have found a web that explains how to do it entirely in SQL:

http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2009/12/22/Call-a-webservice-from-TSQL-%28Stored-Procedure%29-using-MSXML.aspx